# JSRender with JSViews event binding with global helper function throws error e.apply is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsrender, jsviews

When I try to do an event binding which calls a global helper function taking in 3 parameters, a TypeError is thrown stating e.apply is not a function. The functionality is not compromised but the html doesn't render properly (hrefs after the call render as plain text).

My simplified code is as follows:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.views.helpers({
        rapidClick: function(chip, petName, owner, ev, eventArgs) {
            console.log('Data for RapidAlert: ' + chip + ', ' + petName + ', ' + ownerCell);
        }
    });
});
```

```
<script id="matchTempl" type="text/x-jsrender">
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">

        <h2 class="panel-title"><span class="x-chip" data-link="html{:~diff(chip)}"></span>
        {{if ~token && pet}}
            <div class="pull-right">
                <small style="margin-right: 30px">{{:weight}}&percnt;</small>
                <button class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" data-link="{on 'click' ~rapidClick chip pet.name owner}">Send RapidAlert</button>
            </div>
        {{else}}
            <small class="pull-right" style="margin-right: 10px">{{:weight}}&percnt;</small>
        {{/if}}
        </h2>

    </div>

</div>
```

```
<script id="matchTempl" type="text/x-jsrender">
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">

        <h2 class="panel-title"><span class="x-chip" data-link="html{:~diff(chip)}"></span>
        {{if ~token && pet}}
            <div class="pull-right">
                <small style="margin-right: 30px">{{:weight}}&percnt;</small>
                <button class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" data-link="{on 'click' ~rapidClick chip pet.name owner}">Send RapidAlert</button> //If I remove this line, the error is not thrown
            </div>
        {{else}}
            <small class="pull-right" style="margin-right: 10px">{{:weight}}&percnt;</small>
        {{/if}}
        </h2>

    </div>

</div>
```

This is the stack trace from browser inspect:

TypeError
columnNumber: 2959
fileName: "http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsrender/0.9.84/jsrender.min.js"
lineNumber: 3
message: "e.apply is not a function"...

What is causing this?

Comment: The HTML is not valid. (div inside an H2, script tag not closed, etc.) and you don't show your code (diff helper function, call to link() method etc.). It should work, but if not, create a small simplified example on jsfiddle, using the latest unminified jsviews.js, and I'll look more closely.

Comment: Hi Boris, thank you so much for taking the time to reply. My apologies for the missing pieces, it seems my attempt at simplifying my code was not entirely successful. Please see this JSFiddle I created: https://jsfiddle.net/kL2bf64d/8/ I have changed the code so that there are no longer div elements inside h2 elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using incompatible versions:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsrender/0.9.84/jsrender.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsviews/0.9.90/jquery.observable.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsviews/0.9.90/jquery.views.min.js"></script>
```

Obviously you need to use the same version for each, or just use a single jsviews.js file.

http://www.jsviews.com/#download

It might be best to remove this question, as it will likely not be helpful or apply to other people.

Comment: Thank you so much. As I am quite new to coding, this was not so obvious to me. I really appreciate your time. I will take your advise and delete the question by tomorrow, when you have seen my reply.